# Why Observable is only excecuted once

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, signalr, azure-ad-msal

SignalR hub connection can be provided with an auth token either as a string or as a factory method.

I'm using a factory because my auth token can expire, in which case a refresh token is used to get a new auth token.

This is done with the following code:

```js
  public getAccessToken(): Observable<AuthenticationResult> {
    const accounts = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts();
    if (accounts.length === 1) {
      return this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent({ account: accounts[0]});
    } else {
      this.msalService.acquireTokenRedirect();
    }
  }
```

This will return an Observable which is passed to my signalR service in charge of establishing the connection :

```js
 this._realTimeNotificationService.connect(this._authService.getAccessToken(environment.backendUrl));
```

The ´connect´ method looks like this :

```js
connect(accessToken: Observable<any>): Promise<any> {

    const token$ = accessToken.pipe(map(response => response.accessToken));
    const options: IHttpConnectionOptions = {
      accessTokenFactory: () =>
// convert to promise as the factory expects a string or a promise returning a string
        token$.toPromise()
    };

    this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.hubUrl, options)
      
      // doing more stuff here
 }
```

The problem I'm facing is that my token$ observable only fires once. That is when my signalR connection expires and it tries to reconnect automatically, the promise returns the original  auth token (the one that is aready expired).

Instead it should call `getAccessToken()` again but it's not the case. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: In `getAccessToken()`: The `else` block is missing the `return` statement.

Comment: that's not the issue. If the code reaches this  `else` block, the app will redirect the user to a login page. However if user is already logged in, and the token has expired, the call to acquireTokenSilently will use a refresh token to get a new auth token.

Comment: `acquireTokenSilent` needs to return a cold observable if you want to subscribe multiple times and run the function again, otherwise you'll just get the same "completed" observable each time you subscribe. If you want to call `getAccessToken` each time, why not just pass it as a function where you're currently using `accessToken: Observable<any>`?